# Clear cache/indexed pages of a Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: search-engine, google-custom-search

I added a Google Custom Search Engine to a site. There is a search box in the header. It also shows the list of frequently searched keywords. Since, the header was available on all pages, the search engine index all the pages according to these keywords too. This was wrong. I searched and added `class='nocontent'` to the relevant `div`. Now the question:

I want the clear the cache of my custom search engine and force it to reindex pages. How to do that? I have tried to remove the site and add it again but it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to use the "On-Demand Indexing" feature to request updated indexing for your CSE.

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/indexing.html

There are several additional help pages with related information.  I cannot post any further links here (because I lack sufficient rep on Stack Overflow), so I'll tell you how to find those pages:

On the page linked above, under "Other Resources" in the sidebar, click "Help Center"; then click "How to", click "Search results", click "Indexing", and follow the listed links.

NOTE:

At this time the class="nocontent" exclusion feature of Custom Search may not yet work in some cases.  Please see this discussion in the Custom Search forum (and check there again later for any updates):

https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/customsearch/Rz63MiyoU6I/_tSZ_g_9D_AJ

Comment: This is the link @omr mentioned: `http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=16792&parent=1723950&ctx=topic`